# Query fails while inserting from select query in hive partitioned table

Tags: hadoop, hive

Created a table like -

```
create table data_load(
data_4 bigint,
data_4 string
)
partitioned by (data_1 bigint, data_2 bigint, data_3 bigint)
stored as paquet TBLPROPERTIES("parquet.compression"="gzip")`
```

While inserting data into the table it fails -
using query as -

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict; insert into table data_load partition (data_1, data_2, data_3)  select data_4, data_5, data_1, data_2, data_3 from test_table
```

Error -

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask. partition hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/data_load/.hive-staging_hive_2021-04-26_01-39-63_441_251873045434332599-117/-ext-10000/tmpstats-0_FS_3 is not a directory! (state=08S01,code=1)
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if this works

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict; 

CREATE TABLE data_load( data_4 bigint, data_4 string ) partitioned by (data_1 bigint, data_2 bigint, data_3 bigint) stored as paquet TBLPROPERTIES("parquet.compression"="gzip") as
select data_4, data_5, data_1, data_2, data_3 from test_table
```